# How to retrieve images from parse and set UIImageview in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I am building an app which will query a set of images (thumbnails) from the parse server and then show them in a collection view, similar to how is done on instagram in the users profile page. I created a method which queries the data from the backend successfully :

```
-(void)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VideoApp"];
NSString * author = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FBName"];
[query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:author];
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
[query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];



    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects", objects.count);
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            userVideosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objects.count];

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"video_thumbnail"];
                [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"Fetching image");
                        [userVideosArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

}

This method successfully retrieves four objects from the back end, and is called in the ViewDidLoad method.
Then in the collection view cellForRowAtIndexPath method I try to set the queried objects images to the UIImageview on the collectionviewcell as follows:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell * cell = (CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VideoApp"];
   NSString * info = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FBName"];
    [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:info];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[userVideosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];




    return cell;
}
```

I keep getting an NSException on `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[userVideosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` . Not 100 percent sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the whole error message? In `userVideosArray` you already put `UIImage`, so `imageView.image = [userVideosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` should be enough.

Comment: all it says is: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: I'm sure there is more of this message, like the line before it that should start with `**Terminating app due to uncaught exception *** `

Comment: ahh okay sorry. here is the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'` It says its an empty array, although I'm not sure why, because the queryForTable method successfully retrieves four objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

1) `reloadData`: wrong because you did not update any array before doing this. I assume that it is side effect of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` which is definitely wrong, because only object which performs `reloadData` should be responsible for updating data for datasource.

2) initializing `userVideosArray` with no items (`userVideosArray.count == 0`). Looking at your error and knowing that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is invoked I'm assuming that `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` uses other different array to tell the number of items which is wrong, because you are trying to get item from `userVideosArray` which may have different number of items

3) filling `userVideosArray` with items in background. Keeping in mind 1 and 2 gives us an answer to your crash. in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you are trying to obtain item which is still not loaded

Btw: `[cell addSubview:imageView];` will keep adding image views to your cell each time collection view will reuse it

Answer (score 0):

You should update collectionView **after** you have handled received data, not before. Your call to `[self.collectionView reloadData]` trickers calls to `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and my guess is that userVideosArray does not yet contain as many items as you're expecting.

Anyways, the crash. Try this to prevent crashing:

```
if (indexPath.item < userVideosArray.count)
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:userVideosArray[indexPath.item]];
```

Btw when using collectionView, I'd recommend using `item` instead of `row`, since one collectionView row might contain several items. You know now what you're doing, and it's ok to use row, but later row vs. item terms might get confusing.